# andFilter filters out everything

Tags: java, swing, jtable, tablerowsorter

In the following code, even if I set the required values to *CASEID*, *ANY* and *NUM*, the JTable deletes all content. I just can't figure out what i did wrong.

```
public void filter(FilterArgs fa){
    TableRowSorter<TableModel> sorter = new TableRowSorter<TableModel>(); 
    mTable.setRowSorter(sorter);
    ArrayList<RowFilter<Object,Object>> filters = new ArrayList<RowFilter<Object,Object>>(3);
    TableModel model = mModel;
    System.out.println(fa.getCaseID());
    System.out.println(fa.getAlarmID());
    System.out.println(fa.getState());
    System.out.println(fa.getNumAlarms());
    if(!fa.getCaseID().equals("*CASEID*")){
        filters.add(RowFilter.regexFilter(".*"+fa.getCaseID()+".*",0));//filter first column
    }
    else{filters.add(RowFilter.regexFilter(".*",0));}//don't filter first column
    if(!fa.getState().equals("*ANY*")){
        filters.add(RowFilter.regexFilter(".*"+fa.getState()+".*",4));//filter fifth column 
    }
    else{filters.add(RowFilter.regexFilter(".*",4));}
    if(!fa.getNumAlarms().equals("*NUM*")){
        int num = Integer.parseInt(fa.getNumAlarms());
        if(fa.getOperatorNumAlarms().equals("<")){
            filters.add(RowFilter.numberFilter(ComparisonType.BEFORE,num,7));
        }
        if(fa.getOperatorNumAlarms().equals("=")){
            filters.add(RowFilter.numberFilter(ComparisonType.EQUAL,num,7));
        }
        if(fa.getOperatorNumAlarms().equals(">")){
            filters.add(RowFilter.numberFilter(ComparisonType.AFTER,num,7));
        }

    }
    else{filters.add(RowFilter.regexFilter(".*",7));}
    RowFilter<Object,Object> filter = RowFilter.andFilter(filters);
    sorter.setRowFilter(filter); 

}
```

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example).

Comment: With no data to test against, it's not really going to be possible to know where you might be going wrong...